# Drag and Drop of Image

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I have two imageViews and one image on one imageView and other ImageView is empty. I want to Drag image and drop on empty imageView. I also want to make the Image to move back to its first place. simply saying i want to make the image to move between two imageViews. I thing when i drag tha image it also drag the imageView. I want to drag only image not the ImageVew because i have to move image back to its first place.
I tried this and facing problem, any simple solution needed?

```
private final class ChoiceTouchListner implements View.OnTouchListener{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if((event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && ((ImageView)v).getDrawable()!=null){
            ClipData data= ClipData.newPlainText("","");
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder= new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
            v.startDrag(data,shadowBuilder,v,0);
            return true;
        }else{  return false;}

    }
}
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
private class ChoiceDragListner implements View.OnDragListener{
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()){
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                break; //no action necesary
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                ImageView imageView= (ImageView) event.getLocalState(); //the source image
                ((ImageView)v).setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blue));
               // ((ImageView)v).setImageDrawable(null); //replace source by empty
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Android Drag and Drop – Example**

you can try this example.

> > activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomlinear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400px"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#00ff00"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/one"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="Drag Me" />

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottomlinear"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400px"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#00ffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/drop"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:text="Drop Here" />
   <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Total"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Sucess"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

 </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

> > MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button drag;
LinearLayout drop;
TextView text,sucess;
int total , failure = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    drag = (Button)findViewById(R.id.one);
    drop = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.bottomlinear);
    text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Total);
    sucess = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Sucess);

    drop.setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final int action = event.getAction();
        switch(action) {

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
        break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:{
            failure = failure+1;
            return(true);
        }

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:{
            total = total +1;
            int suc = total - failure;
            sucess.setText("Sucessful Drops :"+suc);
            text.setText("Total Drops: "+total);
            return(true);

        }

        default:
        break;
        }
        return true;
        }});
        drag.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(drag);
            v.startDrag(data, shadow, null, 0);
            return false;
        }
    });

}

}
```

Comment: ok. Thanks but thats not what i want. Basically i want that firstly i have two imageViews(imageView1 and imageView2) and both are empty. Suppose I touch on ImageView1 then a image insert on imageView1. And then I want to drag that image and drop on imageVIew2. and vice versa.  
Means we have two imageViews and one image.